# Getting relational data faster with Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using parse to get a number of places into a recyclerview.
The problem is it's quite slow, which probably has to do with my workflow.

In the RecyclerView I show: a picture, some textfields, tags, how many likes a place has, and how many comments.

For this I query my Place object, which has relations with a picture object (which holds a ParseFile), tag objects  & comments object.

**Getting 10 places like this takes about 10 seconds, this seems to be extremely show.**

Worksflow:
in a AsyncTask I have a query to get all the Places.
I do a for loop on these places and per place I get the relations for the pictureUrls, tags & comments. (These are loaded into arraylists to pass to the adapter).

By the way, in the adapter the pictures are loaded with Picasso.

Any help on this would be appreciated :)

Comment: What is slow, loading the whole place objects or images?

Comment: Try querying for a smaller amount of Place objects at a time, and lazily loading them when the user wants to see more. Also, Glide does caching differently than Picasso, and is faster. So, this might as well improve the timing issue.  http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en

Comment: `which has relations with a picture object ` this sounds like it is a pointer and not a relation. If it is a pointer you might want to use `query.include('picture')`, this way removing the need for looping the Place objects. https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#queries-relational-queries

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, for now.

What makes getting the placeobject slow is iterating over each object, getting the relation with picture object, tags & comments.
I dropped this iteration, instead I:

**pictures**
- I stored the url to the thumb in my place object, I load this picture with Picasso

**comments**
- I added a field "commentscount" and increment this everytime there is a one. I just needed the count, so this is enough. (I show the comments in the detailfragment)

**tags**
- I dropped the tags, and I will show them in the details too.

So, dirty fix maybe, but it might be just what this problem needed.. :)